# GRUB 2 boot ubuntu 18 os from usb to boot fresh os to bypass encrypted disk

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, startup

i'm lost, i'll explain:

I successfully booted ubuntu from a usb stick on a old macbook pro, 
I setup disk encryption, account ect...

I then realize that the keyboard doesn't match mine and i setup the password using a "square²" key.
I enter a couple commands to download and use the correct keyboard that doesn't include this key
I try to take as many measures as i can to be able to enter the password when rebooting so that the change takes affect

Impossible to enter that key..

So I decided best was to reboot from the usb and start all over
But i can seem to be able to select the USB from which to boot ubuntu

Please help if anyone can point me in the right direction

Comment: "Square key"?? What do you mean by that?

Comment: to the power of 2 or ^2.. the mathematical notation for multiplying a variable by itself